# Read-only file system

Tags: files, readonly

I am trying to remove write permission for others for this one

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2950421 Jul  7 15:19 fcp_daemon
```

I am using this command and I am performing this action as a root user

```
chmod o-w fcp_daemon
```

but I am getting this error

```
chmod: changing permissions of `fcp_daemon': Read-only file system
```

Comment: Odds are, you're getting the error because the filesystem is read-only.

Comment: @martin If you edit a post for formatting, please look at the spelling, etc., as well while you are at it (an additional 3 errors and begging has no place in a post)

Answer (score 5):

Your filesystem is read-only, probably because it is damaged. This has nothing to do with the file permissions. Check the output of the `dmesg` command if there are any ATA error messages that may indicate a damaged hard disk.

Comment: if I run that dmesg command is any effect to filesystem and any reboot needed

Comment: @kondareddy `man dmesg` will tell you what the command does

Comment: ... Or it's read-only media (CD-ROM or DVD-ROM)...